# Crear diferentes stock's en Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

Tengo un problema, estoy trabajando con **prestashop en su versión 1.7**, no se si es posible o no crear diferentes **stock's** me explico, mis productos están disponibles por ejemplo en diferentes almacenes, uno en la ciudad de México, otro en puebla, otro en Michoacán, etc... mi duda es si puedo definir en prestashop en que almacén esta disponible para que el usuario seleccione el que mas le conviene. por ejemplo el **stock** de la México tiene 50 cantidades de mi producto pero el de puebla es de 0, entonces mi usuario puede seleccionar el de la Ciudad de Mexico o como puedo hacer que al momento de hacer el pedido se seleccione el almacén, es posible manejar diferentes **stock's** ? o deberían ser múltiples tiendas?.

Answer (score 0):

debes activar por obligacion la multitienda, ya que con esta asi solo sea una tienda y distintos almacenes Prestashop lo considera varias tiendas y podras manejar stock en distintos lugares. mismo producto con diferentes stock segun la tienda.